# Joomla registration form

Tags: jquery, forms, joomla, registration, joomla3.0

How i can remove fields in joomla registration form without use the option in background? Or the best hay to put the question, how i remove the call in Jquery?

If i remove the field in backoffice, when i load the page, the form show all the fields during in 1second. but i don't find the place where jquery is calling the form.

```
$js = "
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        // Define the variables
        var regForm     = $('#member-registration');
        var name        = regForm.find('#jform_name');
        var username    = regForm.find('#jform_username');
        var password    = regForm.find('#jform_password1');
        var password2   = regForm.find('#jform_password2');
        var email       = regForm.find('#jform_email1');
        var email2      = regForm.find('#jform_email2');

        // Hide the required field, star, name, confirm pass and confirm email
        regForm.find('.spacer').parents('.control-group').hide();
        regForm.find('.star').hide();
        name.parents('.control-group').hide();
        password2.parents('.control-group').hide();
        email.parents('.control-group').hide();
        email2.parents('.control-group').hide();

        // Add a default value to the name field
//            name.val('Anonymous');

        // Clone password and email values to the confirm fields
        username.on('keyup', function() {
            email.val( this.value );
    email2.val( this.value );
    name.val( this.value );
    username.val( this.value );
        });
        password.on('keyup', function() {
            password2.val( this.value );
        });

    });    
";
```

Thanks.